# Is it legal to use the university's softwares for a personal work made to be published and maybe profited from?

Tags: software

Softwares sometimes cost thousands of dollars which an invidial like me can't afford. A cheaper option for me would be to enlist in a university (this isn't the US here) and use their copy of the software on their computers to do my work. 
The work isn't made for a client, but is made to be published. Is that legal? Maybe even for small parts of the work?

Comment: What does the license for the software say? It almost certainly covers this, and will almost certainly specify that it's for university purposes only, making your proposed use a breach of contract.

Comment: Thanks Nij, it took me some time to find the license... "For Educational Purposes Only". So I'll delete this question

Comment: The question can be generalised, so it still serves a purpose.

Answer (score -1):

You have to check the terms provided by the university. However, in my university, virtually all of the software freely distributed (under site license) to faculty, staff and students is (or was) free of any "purpose" type restrictions. Some items, though, have to be on university machines, on campus, and often have a "delete when you leave" condition.

In light of the revised question, it is also relevant to consider restrictions on using university computers, or more generally someone else's computer, where certain software is already installed on the machine. We can assume that there is some kind of access control on the machines, e.g. a login system so that only authorized users can access the machines. Because you are not copying anything (software-wise), copyright and licensing considerations fall by the wayside. There might however be some kind of restriction on use of the systems, such as "These computers are only to be used for writing term papers". I've never seen such a thing, but it could happen. If the terms of use prohibit using the machines for a given purpose and you do so anyway, then the university could sue you for damages (or, they could toss you out, unless you have a statutory right to attend the university). Then what has to be determined is what those damages are, which I think is a separate and more complex question.

Comment: Sounds dreamy, I'll actually consider asking the university for their license information before I go to it. Although it might be a bit rude, staying legal at home is way too pricey sometimes...